# Error Installing twilio iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, twilio

Pod::StandardError - Unable to find the specification TwilioClient (1.2.9) in the twilio source.
In the pod file:
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'
pod 'TwilioClient', '~>1.2'

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try just `pod 'TwilioClient'` ?

Comment: Yes I did.. Same error.                                                                           source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'
pod 'TwilioClient'
```

### Error

```
Pod::StandardError - Unable to find the specification TwilioClient (1.2.9) in the twilio source.

Comment: atulkhatri You have any idea what else could be the reason? I tried many different things, but no luck. Im not sure where I'm doing wrong

Comment: The answer is given there: https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs/blob/master/TwilioClient/1.2.9/TwilioSDK.podspec by reading the pod spec file or here https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs/blob/master/TwilioClient/1.2.9/TwilioSDK.podspec and by looking for" Twilio" in CocoaPods WebSite. There: https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs/tree/master/TwilioClient you can see the commit message saying that they rename it.

Answer (score 4):

I replaced below line in my podFile. see here https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client

pod 'TwilioSDK', '~>1.2'

Answer (score 0):

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'TwilioSDK', '1.2.9'